# Storing to database from Ajax with JavaScript data in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I'm learning JavaScript, Ajax and Django by building a project.
I'm working an quiz. It has a HTML form that carries the questions and a script written in JavaScript that computes the score.

The form displays correctly and the JavaScript works perfectly well. It give me the required result. 
What I'm not getting is the data being stored into the database using Ajax. It doesn't work. Maybe it's the way I'm doing it, but I can't figure this one out.

The JavaScript code looks like this (the score variable carries the actual users score). I actually have no issues with it, but it might be helpful for solving my problem.

```
function submitAnswers(answers) {
    var total = answers.length;
    var score = 0;
    var choice = []


    //getting choices 
    //new dynamic method 1
    for (var i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
        choice[i] = document.forms["quizForm"]["q" + i].value;
    }

    //validation
    for (i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
        if (choice[i] == null || choice[i] == '') {
            alert('You have not answered question ' + i);
            return false;
        }
    }

    //set correct answer
    //this variable  is replaced by database answer
    //check answer
    // new dynamic method 1 for checking answer
    for (i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
        if (choice[i] == answers[i - 1]) {
            score++;
        }
    }

    //Display Result
    var results = document.getElementById('results');
    results.innerHTML = "<h3>You scored <span>" + score + "</span> out of <span>" + total + "</span></h3>"
    alert("You scored " + score + " out of " + total);

    document.getElementById('btnSubmit').style.display = 'none';

    return false;

}
```

The Ajax code I'm trying our is:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#exams_form', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/exams/',
        data: {
            // the javascript solution from the quiz (gives the users score)
            scoreResult: $('score').val(),
        },
        success: handleSuccess,
        error: handleError,
    });

})
```

In my Django apps view.py for this form, I have:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        scoreResult = request.POST['score']
        course = request.POST['course']

        ExamScores.objects.create(course=course, scoreResult=scoreResult)
```

My models.py looks like this:

```
class ExamScores(models.Model):
    course = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    scoreResult = models.IntegerField()
    examDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I don't really know where my issues are from, I can only guest it probably from the Ajax or views.py file. I expect to have the result sent to the database.

I need some help please.

Comment: Does your django development server show any output? What about the response to your ajax call in the network inspector tab of your browser? Just looking at your code it looks like your ajax call is missing the `'course'` data that `def index` expects, and you'll also need to add the CSRF token to the ajax request for a POST call: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request

Comment: Note that your Ajax is sending `scoreResult` but your view is expecting `score`. You should be able to see the error response in your browser dev tools.

Comment: Dude you're doing request.POST['course'] but in your ajax you're not sending anything named course, you must be getting keyerror for sure, fix that & you'll be good to go. Also dont name your model field in camelCase.